# DataTemplate with textbox for search

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, uwp, datatemplate

I uses [MasterDetailsView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview) control. It has `MasterHeaderTemplate` property. I want to add a `TextBox` in order to implementation of items search. I don't understand how to do this. Because `DataTemplate` don't has a needed property. It's `UWP` app, don't `WPF`.

`TextBlock` got value by `MasterHeader` property. But how do other binding. For example, placeholder text, event handlers.

```
MasterHeader="{x:Bind ViewModel.Title}"
MasterHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MasterHeaderTemplate}"

<DataTemplate
    x:Key="MasterHeaderTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding}"
            Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
        <TextBox
            PlaceholderText="{???}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to bind the placeholder text? Just a normal property on the ViewModel? Can you not to do {Binding DataContext.PlaceholderTextProperty} ?

Comment: @RyanThomas Inside `DataTemplate` don't access to datacontext or my viewmodel.

Comment: I think you are going to have to bind your control you are using the DataTemplate with to an interface that has both a text value and placeholder value. Or you'll have to blindly go up the control chain which might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Binding.ElementName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.elementname) property to set the name of your MasterDetailsView to use as the binding source for the Binding. Then you can access its DataContext(e.g. your ViewModel) and bind the property from ViewModel with PlaceholderText. For example:

.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MasterHeaderTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock
        Text="{Binding}" />
            <TextBox PlaceholderText="{Binding ElementName=MyDetailView,Path=DataContext.PlaceholderText}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <controls:MasterDetailsView
      ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}"
      x:Name="MyDetailView" MasterHeader="{Binding Title}" MasterHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MasterHeaderTemplate}">
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView>
</Grid>
```

.cs:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
    ViewModel.Title = "Header";
    ViewModel.PlaceholderText = "MyPlaceholderText";

    this.DataContext = ViewModel;
}
private MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
```